# Finding the residue for $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}$ at $z_0=i.$

Tags: complex-analysis

From Stein Complex Analysis textbook page 78, when proving $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{1+x^2} \,=\pi$, the text states that
since we may write $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}$$ we see that the residue of $f$ at $i$ is simply $\frac{1}{2i}.$

Can you please explain what is going on here?

I have the formula $$\oint_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz=2\pi i \,\text{Res}_{z_0} f(z),$$ but I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: What's exactly your question? Is it how wo calculate the residue of $f$ or is it how to use the residue theorem to calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: Hahaha!  Nice point.  So far all the answers show how to compute the residue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to see that the residue at $i$ of $f(z)$ is $\frac{1}{2i}.$  Here is one:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)} =\frac{1}{2i}\left( \frac{1}{z-i} - \frac{1}{z+i}\right).$$

The first term already displays the residue,$\frac{1}{2i}(z-z_0)^{-1}$, with $z_0=i,$ and the second term is holomorphic at $z_0=i$.

**UPDATE**

If the question is how to apply this to the real integral given, consider the contour $C$ that consists of the line from $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis, closed by a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper-half plane.  This contour encloses the point $z_0=i$, the only pole in the upper-half plane.

Consider $$\oint_C \frac{dz}{1+z^2}$$ and let $R\to\infty.$  The integral along the semicircle goes to zero, and we are left with $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}.$$  Surely the textbook by Stein and Shakarchi gives these details $\cdots.$

Answer (score 4):

The residue can be defined as the coefficient of the term of order $-1$ in the Laurent series... If $f(z)= \sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ the residue is just $\textrm{Res}(f,z_0) = a_{-1}$. Also, if there is only a finite number of terms with negative index, i.e.
$$
f(z) = \frac{a_{-p}}{(z-z_0)^p} + \cdots + \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)} + \cdots
$$

you can multiply both terms by $(z-z_0)^p$ and differentiate $p-1$ times to get

$$
\textrm{Res}(f,z_0) =\frac{1}{(p-1)!} \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{d^{p-1}}{dz^{p-1}}\left((z-z_0)^p f(z) \right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is analytic on a neighborhood of $z_0\in\Bbb C$, then the residue at $z_0$ of $\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}$ is equal to $g(z_0)$.

Now consider the above paragraph using the function $g(z)=\frac{1}{z+i}$. It is analytic on a neighborhood around $z_0=i$.

Answer (score 1):

In your example as $x=i$ is a simple pole, we can use the following formula
$$\text{Res} (f,c)=\lim _{z\to c}(z-c)f(z)$$
that is

$$\text{Res}(f,i)=\lim _{z\to i}(z-i)\cdot\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}=\frac{1}{2i}$$

Comment: This formula only holds if $c$ is a pole of order $1$ (or if $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=c$. It is ok in this case, but in general this limit may not exist with the residue still being well defined.

Answer (score 1):

You choose the path $\mathcal C$ as semicircle: going from $-R$ to $R$ and then close the semicircle by circumnavigate the point $i$ (so the upper part of the semicircle which you can imagine geometrically as the shape of a rotated D), whereas $R\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ denotes the radius of the circle. For this integral you can use the residue theorem as you already showed and the result is independent of the radius $R$. Now you just have to show that the integrals $\int_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{1+x^2}$ are equal. The solution is (we denote the path dependent of the radius $R$ by $\mathcal C_R $) to consider $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\mathcal{C}_R}f(z)dz.$$ Denote $\Gamma_R$ the "upper ring" of the path $\mathcal C_R$.
You can show that $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)dz=0$$ holds. For this use $$\left|\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)dz\right|\leq \sup_{z\in\Gamma_R}|f(z)|\cdot L(\Gamma_R),$$ where $L(\Gamma_R)$ denotes the length of the curve $\Gamma_R$.
Finally you have $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\mathcal{C}_R}f(z)dz-\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{1+x^2}.$$